# hive table export to other hadoop cluster or hive export within cluster+ distcp?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, distcp

I want to export hive table from one Hadoop cluster A  to another B.

I have 2 approaches:

First:

- **export** to hdfs of A (*same cluster*)
- **distcp** to hdfs of cluster B(*different cluster*)
- **import** to hive of cluster B

Second:

- **export** to hdfs of B (*different cluster*)
- **import** to hive of cluster B

Is **distcp** adding extra advantage?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "export to HDFS" and "import to Hive". The Hive data files *are* stored in HDFS anyway!

For a managed table, with all these data files located under the same "location" in a deterministic way, the simplest thing to do is:

- create an empty managed table in cluster B with *exactly* the same layout and Serde -- also creating all expected partitions, if any
- `distcp` the whole HDFS tree from "location" in A to "location" in B
- done!

That's what we do to clone some Prod data *(ORC w/ GZip compression, partitioned by month)* to a Test cluster.

Note that you can restrict the copy to a list of partitions, using multiple `distcp` commands on single sub-directories.

Comment: how will you  _create an empty managed table in cluster B with exactly the same layout and Serde_?

Comment: You've got the original `CREATE TABLE` script archived in a code repo (Git, SVN, etc), right? Just run it again on the other cluster

Comment: It's like fetching data from customer's cluster & we don't have those scripts. We have no information of tables' metadata.

Comment: Run HQL command `describe table extended` then translate the JSON vomit at the end into a valid CREATE script.

Comment: But then if you are **scraping data illegally from a third-party database**, do it at your own risk.